# How do I loop through XML nodes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to loop through XML nodes containing information about users to create an HTML table on my website.

This is what the XML looks like:

```
<websites_name>
<user>...</user>
<user>...</user>
.
.
.
</websites_name>
```

And this is the code I'm trying to parse it with:

```
for(var user in xmlhttp.getElementsByTagName('user')){   //fix this row to me
    //Create a new row for tbody
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    document.getElementById('tbody').appendChild(tr);
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","some URL",true);
xmlhttp.send();
var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
var root = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('websites_name');
for(var i=0, i<root[0].childNodes.length,i++){
    //Create a new row for tbody
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    document.getElementById('tbody').appendChild(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One of the least intuitive things about parsing XML in JavaScript is that the text inside the element tags is actually a node you have to traverse into.

Assuming it's `<user>text data</user>`, you not only have to traverse into the text node of the user element to extract your text data, but you have to create a text node with that data in the DOM to see it. See [nodeValue](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_node_nodevalue.asp) and and [createtextnode](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_document_createtextnode.asp):

```
// get XML 
var xml = xhr.responseXML;

// get users
var users = xml.getElementsByTagName("user");
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {   
    var user = users[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(user);
    td.appendChild(textNode);        
    tr.appendChild(td);        
    document.getElementById("tbody").appendChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: I've located the problem it lies in the row "var root = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("websites_name");".What have I done wrong? Look at my update. Your solution is the same except for the textNode. It is actually mor XML nodes under user

Comment: ok I know what the problem was. A very minor. The scripts that produced my XML , I forgot the row "header("Content-type: text/xml");"

Comment: awesome - yeah, that content type stuff is super important with ajax. this stuff is a lot easier with libraries like jquery ...