# Displaying xml information in html via ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I'm working on a web radio station, and a program through which streaming (jazler) has the ability to send xml files (containing information such as current song name, previous song ..) via ftp to a web server and these files are automatically updated when the song changes..

NowOnAir.xml code:

```
<Schedule System="Jazler">
    <Event status="happening" startTime="10:05:40" eventType="song">
        <Announcement Display=""/>
        <Song title="Forbidden Voices">
            <Artist name="Martin Garrix"> </Artist>
            <Jazler ID="7304"/>
            <PlayLister ID=""/>
            <Media runTime="03:05"/>
            <Expire Time="10:08:44"/>
        </Song>
    </Event>
</Schedule>
```

Immediately to note, I am not a programmer, and I know very little about coding! I found the following script on the Internet and tested it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script>
var speed = 10000; // 10 seconds

function $(e){if(typeof e=='string')e=document.getElementById(e);return e};
function collect(a,f){var n=[];for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){var v=f(a[i]);if(v!=null)n.push(v)}return n};

ajax={};
ajax.x=function(){try{return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP')}catch(e) {try{return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')}catch(e){return new XMLHttpRequest()}}};
ajax.serialize=function(f){var g=function(n){return f.getElementsByTagName(n)};var nv=function(e){if(e.name)return encodeURIComponent(e.name)+'='+encodeURIComponent(e.value);else return ''};var i=collect(g('input'),function(i){if((i.type!='radio'&&i.type!='checkbox')||i.checked)return nv(i)});var s=collect(g('select'),nv);var t=collect(g('textarea'),nv);return i.concat(s).concat(t).join('&');};
ajax.send=function(u,f,m,a){var x=ajax.x();x.open(m,u,true);x.onreadystatechange=function(){if(x.readyState==4)f(x.responseText)};if(m=='POST')x.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');x.send(a)};
ajax.get=function(url,func){ajax.send(url,func,'GET')};
ajax.gets=function(url){var x=ajax.x();x.open('GET',url,false);x.send(null);return x.responseText};
ajax.post=function(url,func,args){ajax.send(url,func,'POST',args)};
ajax.update=function(url,elm){var e=$(elm);var f=function(r){e.innerHTML=r};ajax.get(url,f)};
ajax.submit=function(url,elm,frm){var e=$(elm);var f=function(r){e.innerHTML=r};ajax.post(url,f,ajax.serialize(frm))};

function process(xml) {
document.getElementById('contentfile').innerHTML=xml;
var title = document.getElementById('contentfile').getElementsByTagName('Song')[0].title;
var name = document.getElementById('contentfile').getElementsByTagName('Artist')[0].name;
document.getElementById('contentfile').innerHTML='NOW ON AIR: '+name+' | '+title;
}
function checkXml() {
ajax.get('http://website.com/jazler/NowOnAir.xml',process)
}
window.onload=function() {
checkXml();
tId=setInterval('checkXml()',speed)
}

</script>

</head>
<body >
<div id="contentfile">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this shows the name of the current song, but where the name of the author should be written, it says "undefined".

NOTE: Everything is on the wordpress platform..

Comment: did you check on the data elements of the variable?

Comment: I do not know how, I'm not a programmer and I do not understand, can you explain a little better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`title` and `name` are attributes so I would suggest using the `getAttribute` method like so :

```
var title = document.getElementById('contentfile').getElementsByTagName('Song')[0].getAttribute("title");
var name = document.getElementById('contentfile').getElementsByTagName('Artist')[0].getAttribute("name");
```

I've tested this with your code and it display `NOW ON AIR: Martin Garrix | Forbidden Voices`.

**Edit for further explaining :**
I'll also like to add that the reason `title` was working was because you are putting your XML directly in your HTML DOM and `title` is an HTML DOM property.
It would be best to create a new DOM document to store the XML :

```
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");
var title = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Song')[0].getAttribute("title");
var name = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Artist')[0].getAttribute("name");
```

Comment: I have another question if it's not a problem.. I have an xml file called AirPlayHistory.xml that shows the last 3 songs that are streamed and when I use this code it only shows me one.. Can this be done to show last 3 songs?

Comment: AirPlayHistory CODE: `<Event status="happened">
<Song title="TO THE MOON AND BACK [RELEASED BY A!EX]">
<Artist name="SAVAGE GARDEN" ID="344264"> </Artist>
<Info StartTime="10:50:44" JazlerID="11891" PlayListerID=""/>
</Song>
<Song title="LJULJAJ ME NEZNO">
<Artist name="JELENA TOMASEVIC" ID="344042"> </Artist>
<Info StartTime="10:55:05" JazlerID="7485" PlayListerID=""/>
</Song>
<Song title="BIG">
<Artist name="FLAMINGOSI FEAT. NEVENA BOZOVIC" ID="344329"> </Artist>
<Info StartTime="10:58:44" JazlerID="7318" PlayListerID=""/>
</Song>
</Event>`

Comment: I've edit my answer to add further explaining. If you have another problem (different than this question) you should open a new question.

Comment: But for multiples songs you might want to look into `for` loop, [this could help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362392/how-do-i-loop-through-a-xml-nodes-in-javascript)